# insert a double backslash using sed

Tags: sed, escaping, backslash

I want to insert the line

```
text \\
```

into a file via sed. For one backslash to be inserted I would use three backslashes in the command. But escaping does not work for two backslashes:

```
sed -i 'text \\\\\\' $file
```

gives the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 57: unknown command: `
'
```

Comment: `char 57: unknown command:`? Where is the rest of the command you are using? Why do you think `'text \\\\\\'` will have any affect on a file, there is NO sed command to `insert, append, substitute (or delete) in what you show? Good luck.

Comment: Your example suggests that you wanted echo \\\\ > file instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do something like:

`sed -i 's/OLDTEXT/text \\\\/' $file`

You need 4 backslashes when trying to add 2. 3 for 1, 4 for 2 etc :)

Answer (score 1):

With an input file like this:

```
apple
orange
grape
```

You can insert `text \\` in front of `orange` like this:

```
sed -i 's/^orange/text \\\\\n&/' input.txt
```

What this literally does is match the line starting with `orange`, replace the matched string with `text \\` + a newline + the matched string, effectively inserting `text \\` right in front of the line, that is:

```
apple
text \\
orange
grape
```

Note that it takes 4 backslashes to get 2 inserted. I don't know you meant about 3 backslashes for 1, you must be overlooking something there.

Comment: The `-ie` switch creates a backup file appending letter `e` to the input file name, in your example `input.txte`. The `-i` needs a space for an in-place modification. At least for the GNU version. Also because `-e` is not mandatory, it doesn't complain.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/PATTERN/i\text \\\\' file
```

This will overwrite the original `file` and insert `text \\` before the line(s) containing the word `PATTERN`.